# Serenity/Selenium browser closes immediately

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

I am using Serenity bdd 1.53 and the newest chrome driver.
When tests are running browser closes almost immediately and Selenium throws an error "Web driver exception: unknown error: jQuery is not defined".

I was trying to wait for jquery to load, but the result is the same almost all the time.

```
 public boolean waitForJSandJQueryToLoad() {
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    // wait for jQuery to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                return ((Long)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // no jQuery present
                return true;
            }
        }
    };

    // wait for Javascript to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState")
                    .toString().equals("complete");
        }
    };

    return wait.until(jQueryLoad) && wait.until(jsLoad);
}
```

Tried to wait also for the whole page to load, but the same things happen.

```
    void waitForLoad() {
    new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 30).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
            ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
}
```

The tests work well on my local VM, but as I try to test on an external server this problem always occurs.

What could be the reason for this problem?

EDIT:
Stack trace

```
 Web driver exception: unknown error: jQuery is not defined
(Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 6 milliseconds
```

Comment: Have you tried with both? wait for the page to be loaded and after wait for jQuery.

Comment: Yes I did, also tried ordinary wait for like 30 seconds. It just doesn't work and browser closes after about 1-2 seconds. I am out of ideas, what could cause this problem.

Comment: The thing is that you cannot wait for jQuery to load with `jQuery.active` since you don't have any jQuery loaded yet, you need to have it before using it. If you tried with ordinary wait than maybe something is different and you don't have jQuery at all.

Comment: OK but shouldn't Selenium wait for given time and then throw jQuery error? I mean when i use ordinary wait , the first thing that Selenium should do after browser is opened is wait for 30 seconds, but it's just terminating the browser.

Comment: can you post stack trace for the error?

Comment: Yes, I have posted it in edit.

Comment: You have a wait until, in this time selenium checks the condition and increases the time, so the condition is checked from the beginning and there it fails. If the condition true earlier, at 5 sec let say then the load is done, else it will check it until is is true or the timeout expires.